# Mysterious problem...can remotely connect to a system but can't browse back out

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking

I have LogMeIn installed on my home system.  I went on travel and my wife called saying that none of our home systems could browse the internet.  I thought I would try to connect to my home system using logmein.  Surprisingly, I was able to connect to my home system and log in without any problems using logmein.  When I opened a browser from my home system, I indeed could not browse.  I opened a command prompt and tried to ping my router (192.168.1.1) and it failed/timed out.  How is this possible?  I can remotely connect to my system but once logged in cannot even ping my router.  What's up with that?

Comment: Obviously your connection is up so the issue is either your firewall  or the router. Since you couldn't ping the router, I'd disable the firewall first; it might need updated or upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More troubleshooting is necessary.  Things to try (what I would do).  Uninstall LogMeIn from all computers.  Reset your router (and this will reset the default gateway back to 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1).  Re-establish network connectivity and the ability to connect to the outside world and the internet.

Then, after you can connect to the WWW, change your home network to something like 192.168.5.0/24 (this means the router would site on 192.168.5.1).  Assign your home network the range of something like 192.168.5.10 to 192.168.5.100.

Then, go back and reinstall LogMeIn.  Since you have changed your network IPs, this should work fine now.  Also, you may want to turn off all your firewall tools (and maybe AV software too) while troubleshooting this process.  These can interfere with this program and VPNs.